# Perl DBI breaking when data returned is bigint

Tags: perl, sybase

I am having a really weird issue.  I am using perl dbi and calling a stored procedure.  When procedure `get_users` is called I am getting data returned one of the column's data type is bigint.  When I call another stored procedure `user_data` which has bigint as a column's data type.  The procedure fails.  Doing a trace I get `ct_describe() failed` and `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.  On the working stored procedure I am getting a return type:

```
 ct_describe(8): type = 33, maxlen = 8
 describe() -> col 8, type 0, realtype 33
```

Comment: What DBD driver do you use? What version? What Perl version? What OS?

Comment: I am using sybase driver and `syb_server_version` prints `16.0 SP03 PL06`. Perl version `Perl version: 5.030000` OS `Ubuntu 20.04`

Comment: Also run `$ perl -MDBI\ 9` (that's a backslash and a space) and the same for your DBD:: module.

Comment: `DBI version 9 required--this is only version 1.634`  `perl -MDBD\ 9` errors with can't locate DBD.pm.  Not sure why that error is happening because the DBD.pm is found in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30/DBD/` path.  Which is one of the environment paths

Comment: @simbabque Yoo can use `-MDBI=9`

Answer (score -1):

I changed the data type in the database to not allow nulls.